# Fitnesse Eclipse plugin - How to convert eclipse project to Fitnesse project

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to use Fitnesse plugin available at:
http://fitnesse-eclipse.github.io/#intro

I have downloaded and installed the plugin in eclipse. I can see a new option 'FitNesse' on my tool bar and when I right-click on the project I can see the option of 'FitNesse->Open in Browser' as well. The thing which I am not able to get is that the user-guide mentions an option to convert the project to FitNesse Project. I do not get this option when I right-click on the project.

Is this something anyone else came across while using this plugin or am I the only one. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the Open in Browser, it looks like you have already converted to a fitness project. what version of the plugin are you using?

it may be that you have installed the (https://code.google.com/p/fitnesse-editor/)

Comment: fitnesse-eclipse is a fork of the fitnesse-editor as the it was no longer maintained or developed